# Fermat's last theorem and $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, ring-theory

I heard that one can prove special cases of FLT by using unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$ (whenever this is possible), where $\xi$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. How can one do this in detail, and is it known for which natural $n$ $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$ is not a UFD? I mean assuming that $n$ is such that $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$, how does one proceed?

A reference is good enough.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field#Relation_with_Fermat.27s_Last_Theorem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one#Cyclotomic_fields - in particular, there are only finitely many $n$ for which the cyclotomic ring _is_ a UFD.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks, this answers the second question.

Comment: See the first chapter from Marcus' book "Number Fields".

Comment: It's probably done in Harold M. Edwards' book, Fermat's Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: There is a sketch of the proof you want at https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node9.html under the discussion of whether Fermat could have had a proof.

Comment: There is a link to Lame's proof at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953462/what-was-lames-proof

Comment: Expanding on the comment of @Joe, Marcus does exactly what you want --- but the proof is not as short and simple as you hope. In fact, he puts most of the work into a series of 13(!) exercises. Even for a 500-point bounty, I'm not going to type out all those exercises, much less post solutions here, but if you are really interested in seeing how it's done then the Marcus book is the place to go.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I agree with everything you say. Thanks for pointing out the links.

Comment: Finally, the most important reason for which Marcus' book is excellent, is that Mathematics is not a contemplative discipline. The real Mathematics doesn't admit spectators. Actors only. If I had the entire first chapter of Marcus already written, with all the exercise solved, I would probably copied here all the stuff without exercises' solutions. Reading a subject as long as is this, would be incredibly boring, heavy and most of all, not constructive.

Comment: Go to the Marcus' book, read the first chapter solving the exercises: the satisfaction, the skill, the competence you can gain with a work like this is something you'll never get from studying a paper in which all is written down. Knowledge borns from doubt. The less you doubt in your reading, the less you ask yourself, the less you skill yourself as mathematician.

Answer (score 11):

I think you refer to a theorem of Kummer: Fermat's Last Theorem is true for an odd prime $p$ if and only if $p$ doe *not* divide the class number of the cyclotomic extension $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$, i. e. the order of the group of fractionary ideals of this field modulo principal ideals.

Such a prime number is called a *regular* prime.

*Kummer criterion:*

An odd prime $p$ is regular if and only if $p$ does not divide the numerators of the Bernoulli numbers: $\, B_2, B_4,\dots, B_{p-3}$.

All odd primes up to $31$ regular. It is not known if there is an infinity of regular primes.

In case $\mathbf Z(\zeta_p)$ is a UFD, which is equivalent to being a PID, the class number is equal to $1$, hence  $p$ doen't divide it, so Fermat Last Theorem is true for these primes, of which the complete list is:
$$\{3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}$$

Comment: I have seen this notion of a regular prime everywhere, but why can't one just say: ok we assume that $n$ is s.t. $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_n]$ is a UFD, and now we prove it? Just assuming that it is a UFD. Do you know how to do this? Apparently the proof shouldn't be too long.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem holds for any odd prime, including irregular ones. Kummer was only able to prove it for regular primes.

Comment: There are only 30 values of $n$ such that $\mathbf Z[\zeta_n]$ is a UFD. It is *not* equivalent, for $ n$ an odd prime, to be regular, , although all odd primes among the 30 are regular..

Comment: Yes I know, this was pointed out above. I still think the proof should be very interesting, even though it is probably a special case of this theorem of Kummer. I also expect the proof to be much simpler

Comment: @ulli It's more or less given in the first link in my comment: we have factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ of $x^n+y^n$ and of $z^n$, and can show that they aren't related by multiplying by units (as they would need to be if unique factorization holds).

Comment: @ulli: I updated  my answer with a short proof, based on Kummer's theorem (the real job, of course,  would be giving a proof of Kummer's theorem).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: yes, and my question is asking for details in this argument, a complete proof. Bernard: I am looking for a direct argument along the lines of what Steven says, not using Kummer's theorem. (It was clear to me that Kummer's theorem includes this result).

Answer (score 8):

Since you told that "a reference is good enough", since first chapter of Marcus' book "Number Field" is the very right place to go and since writing down a complete and detailed answer is a huge work -even if rewarded with +$500$ as already pointed out-, I'm writing this reference suggestion as an answer, simply because reasonably this IS a good answer.

Comment: I actually wanted to encourage you to post this as an answer, but I was too lazy. You will probably get the 500, unless someone gives a more detailed answer. If no one does this, I will perhaps edit your answer and include a (very rough) sketch of the proof, unless you disagree with this.

Comment: I studied on Marcus' book: any sufficiently detailed proof is really a huge work. The other possibility is, as you said, a rough sketch of the proof. To me there is no problem if you want to edit my answer provided that you write your name under the edit and it is (in its roughness), precise, well done. Obvious requests, do you agree? :-)

Comment: I agree, of course. I actually thought that the proof would be much shorter, but little did I know. The relationship between FLT and the factoriality of $\mathbf{Z}[\xi_n]$ is well-known, but the usual description merely consists of writing down the factorization of $x^n+y^n$, without giving more details. So I think the book of Marcus is rare in this aspect, and I am very grateful to you for providing this reference. I somehow never managed to find a reference (apart from references for the more general Kummer result).